# How can I programmatically trigger custom plugin state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am using following slider plugin [Ion range slider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html), as you can see in first example it has a `onChange` state. I am trying to figure out how to call it programmatically i.e. without touching the slider.

Comment: have you tried `$('#yourSlider').trigger('change');`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I did, as well as 'onChange'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the more ideal approach would be for the plugin to be firing custom events that you could also trigger, you can directly access the change function by first accessing the options object stored in `ionRangeSlider` dataset:

```
$('#range_43').data('ionRangeSlider').options.onChange();
```

This then in turn executes whatever callback may be in place for the `change` event.